# Laravel 5.2 using named route in setting protected redirectPath

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I am looking to redirect after  login to a page with url `/dashboard/start`

My `routes.php` contains the following route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard/start', ['uses' => 'Settings\OrganisationController@index', 'as' => 'app.home']);
```

In Laravel Auth process you can implement a login redirect override by adding a declaration at the start of the `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` controller like so:

```
protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard/start';
```

I want to use named routes throughout the code so that if I change the url in the routes file, it does not impact the code so long as the name has not changed.

I tried this but is fails:

```
protected $redirectPath = route('app.home');
```

I cannot find an example nor a mention of this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. You could override the `redirectPath` method on the controller.

```
protected $redirectPath = 'app.home';

public function redirectPath()
{
    return route($this->redirectPath);
}
```

You also could make an `authenticated` method. The `handleUserWasAuthenticated` method (that gets called when `Auth::attempt` is successful)  checks for existence of the `authenticated` method and if it exists it will call it and return the results instead of the normal `redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())`. This method would receive the current request and authed user.

How `handleUserWasAuthenticated` calls `authenticated`:

```
return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::user());
```

Answer (score -1):

You can redirect many way . you can redirect by route . 
write your routes.php

```
Route::get('first-route',['uses'=>'TestController@first','as'=>'first']);
Route::get('second-route',['as'=>'second','uses'=>'TestController@second']);
```

and write your controller

```
public function first(){
        return "This is a simple Test Controller";
    }
    public function second(){
        return redirect()->route('first');
    }
```

and you can use action method like this

```
public function second(){
        return redirect()->action('TestController@first');
    }
```

or

```
 public function second(){
       $url=action('TestController@first');
        return redirect($url);
    }
```

Comment: how does this help adjust the AuthController redirect path ?